# Update Cell in DataGridView Else Make New Row

Tags: c#, for-loop

I have two DataGridView Tables. One contains all the products and quantity available `MO_CatData`
[image]

The second is the items you add to the table. `MO_quantityData`
[image]

Now, if I choose a selected row from `MO_CatData` and click `Add to Order` it should loop through `MO_quantityData`. If the Product ID is already inside the table then we just update the quantity; Else we make a new Row.

So to get the product ID in the `MO_CatData` I've used:

```
int id = Convert.ToInt32(MO_CatData.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value);
```

Then I want to use a `for` loop and check whether it exists; if it does it'll update otherwise create a new row:

```cs
else
{
    int id = Convert.ToInt32(MO_CatData.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value);
    for (int i = 0; i < MO_quantityData.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(id);

        if (Convert.ToInt32(MO_quantityData.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value) == id)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Gets to if");
            qty = Convert.ToInt32(MO_quantity.Text);
            int newQty = Convert.ToInt32(MO_quantityData.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value) + qty;
            table.Rows[i][3] = newQty;

            float totalprice = newQty * price;
            totalPrice = totalprice;
            sum += totalPrice;

            table.Rows[i][5] = totalPrice;
            MO_quantityData.DataSource = table;
            MO_CatData.Refresh();
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("ELESLESLELES");
            num = num + 1;

            qty = Convert.ToInt32(MO_quantity.Text);

            float totalprice = qty * price;
            totalPrice = totalprice;

            table.Rows.Add(num, product, prodID, qty, price, totalprice);
            MO_quantityData.DataSource = table;
            MO_CatData.Refresh();

            flag = 0;
            sum += totalPrice;
        }
    }
}
```

I feel as if my logic is incorrect somewhere because if I try to add 2 Pizza, then 1 Chicken then another pizza I get:

[image]

Is using a for statement wrong in this scenario? I thought it would be just as simple as loop through the table, if the increment of the loop, at cell 2 is equal to the selectedRow then update quantity else make a new row but clearly not.

Comment: You need to break out of your for loop if you find the id, otherwise it will add the pizza again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you break the code up a little, you will probably see what goes wrong: You need to stop the search when you find the right product. I've added a `FindRowWithId` function that takes care of finding it, and the rest is left as is. You would probably also benefit from only having the price calculations and so on in one place.

```cs
private int FindRowWithId(int id)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < MO_quantityData.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        if (Convert.ToInt32(MO_quantityData.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value) == id)
        {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1; // Not found;
}

...
else
{
    int id = Convert.ToInt32(MO_CatData.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value);
    int foundRow = FindRowWithId(id);
    if (foundRow > -1)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Gets to if");
        qty = Convert.ToInt32(MO_quantity.Text);
        int newQty = Convert.ToInt32(MO_quantityData.Rows[foundRow].Cells[3].Value) + qty;
        table.Rows[foundRow][3] = newQty;
        float totalprice = newQty * price;
        totalPrice = totalprice;
        sum += totalPrice;

        table.Rows[foundRow][5] = totalPrice;
        MO_quantityData.DataSource = table;
        MO_CatData.Refresh();
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("ELESLESLELES");
        num = num + 1;

        qty = Convert.ToInt32(MO_quantity.Text);

        float totalprice = qty * price;
        totalPrice = totalprice;

        table.Rows.Add(num, product, prodID, qty, price, totalprice);
        MO_quantityData.DataSource = table;
        MO_CatData.Refresh();

        flag = 0;
        sum += totalPrice;
    }
}
```